# numpy advanced indexing : how to mask specific labels out in 3-D or higher dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Very often I use the following indexing trick:

```
E[y, np.arange(E.shape[1])] -= 1
```

`E` is a `2-D` array, `y` is `1-D` array and has the same length as `E.shape[1]`, which is used in computing the `softmax loss` for backprop.
If I want to mask some specific label(e.g., value `2`) in `y` I do that by:

```
mask = ~(y == 2)
E[y[mask], np.range(E.shape[1])[mask]] -= 1
```

for a generated example:

```
E = np.arange(32).reshape(4, 8)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]])
y = np.random.randint(4, size=8)
array([2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])
```

Without masking (in the normal case), we can write:

```
E[y, np.arange(E.shape[1])]=100
E
array([[  0, 100, 100,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10, 100,  12,  13, 100, 100],
       [100,  17,  18,  19, 100, 100,  22,  23],
       [ 24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31]])
```

then with mask, we can do:

```
mask = ~(y == 2)
E[y[mask], np.arange(t.shape[1])[mask]] = 1000
E
array([[   0, 1000, 1000,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7],
       [   8,    9,   10, 1000,   12,   13, 1000, 1000],
       [ 100,   17,   18,   19,  100,  100,   22,   23],
       [  24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31]])
```

And in the `3-D` case, we can do a similar thing for basic indexing without a mask:

```
m, n = E.shape[1:]
I, J = np.ogrid[:m, :n]
E[y, I, J] -= 1
```

But I don't know how to perform mask like operations in `3-D` or higher dimensional arrays, can someone help?

Comment: @Divakar Could you pls share your idea?

Comment: You are making me awfully nostalgic for matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 : Getting indices along each axes**

One approach would be getting the row, column indices for the `2D` mask and then indexing with those row, column indices as the indexing arrays for the last two axes and indexing into `y` with those for getting the masked `y` version for indexing along the first axis of `E`. Hence, we could do -

```
I_idx, J_idx = np.where(mask)
E[y[I_idx, J_idx], I_idx, J_idx] -= 1
```

**Approach #2 : Using broadcasting and masking**

Another approach would be to leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to generate a mask for `masking` for the entire array and then perform the intended operation -

```
E[(y == np.arange(E.shape[0])[:,None,None]) & mask] -= 1
```

---

#### Benchmarking

Approaches as functions -

```
# @Paul Panzer's solution
def paul(E, y, mask):
    m, n = E.shape[1:]
    I, J = np.mgrid[:m, :n]
    E[y[mask], I[mask], J[mask]] -= 1
    return E

# From this post
def app1(E, y, mask):
    I_idx, J_idx = np.where(mask)
    E[y[I_idx, J_idx], I_idx, J_idx] -= 1
    return E

# From this post
def app2(E, y, mask):
    E[(y == np.arange(E.shape[0])[:,None,None]) & mask] -= 1
    return E
```

**Timings**

Case #1 : (100, 100, 100) shaped data with around 50% True values in mask

```
In [173]: N = 100 # datasize factor
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: E = np.random.rand(N,N,N)
     ...: E1 = E.copy()
     ...: E2 = E.copy()
     ...: E3 = E.copy()
     ...: mask = np.random.rand(N,N) > 0.5
     ...: y = np.random.randint(0,N,(N,N))

In [174]: %timeit paul(E1, y, mask)
     ...: %timeit app1(E2, y, mask)
     ...: %timeit app2(E3, y, mask)
1000 loops, best of 3: 326 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 220 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 833 µs per loop
```

Case #2 : (100, 100, 100) shaped data with around 90% True values in mask

```
In [177]: N = 100 # datasize factor
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: E = np.random.rand(N,N,N)
     ...: E1 = E.copy()
     ...: E2 = E.copy()
     ...: E3 = E.copy()
     ...: mask = np.random.rand(N,N) > 0.1
     ...: y = np.random.randint(0,N,(N,N))

In [178]: %timeit paul(E1, y, mask)
     ...: %timeit app1(E2, y, mask)
     ...: %timeit app2(E3, y, mask)
1000 loops, best of 3: 244 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 230 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

Case #3 : (100, 100, 100) shaped data with around 10% True values in mask

```
In [183]: N = 100 # datasize factor
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: E = np.random.rand(N,N,N)
     ...: E1 = E.copy()
     ...: E2 = E.copy()
     ...: E3 = E.copy()
     ...: mask = np.random.rand(N,N) > 0.9
     ...: y = np.random.randint(0,N,(N,N))

In [184]: %timeit paul(E1, y, mask)
     ...: %timeit app1(E2, y, mask)
     ...: %timeit app2(E3, y, mask)
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 55 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 635 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mgrid` instead of `ogrid`. Then you can mask as in the 2D case:

```
y = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
mask = y != 2
E = np.arange(18).reshape(3, 2, 3)

m, n = E.shape[1:]
I, J = np.mgrid[:m, :n]
E[y[mask], I[mask], J[mask]] -= 1
```

Value of `E`:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  1],
        [ 2,  4,  5]],

       [[ 5,  7,  8],
        [ 9,  9, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```